# Reduce the gap between tablayout and view pager

Tags: android, android-layout

I have view pager and tablayout defined in my activity in tablayout I am showing dot indicators.Though it is working perfectly but I want to reduce the gap between tablayout and view pager.

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

**Layout file**

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/homeOffers"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**View pager item layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    app:contentPadding="3dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/offerImage"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Someone please let me know how can I achieve he desired layout.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Check you must have provided some margins in row layout of your viewpager content. Remove them.

Comment: Please show your viewpager item layout

Comment: I have updated my post please take a look.

Comment: @Digvijay remove `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` from your `cardview`

Comment: @Nilesh, nothing happens after removing    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout like this -

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/homeOffers"/>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    android:layout_below="@id/homeOffers/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And remove this line from your cardview -

```
   app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```